# NgRx-etc: Cannot assign to read only property 'Property' of object '[Object]'

Tags: angular, ngrx, immer.js

So i have this in my reducer:

```
export interface PersonState {
  person: Person;
}
```

which has an array of relatives inside and i'm trying to update it with this:

```
mutableOn(PersonActions.addRelatives, (state, { relatives }) => {
    const person = state.person;
    person.relatives = relatives;
})
```

but it gave me an error:

> Cannot assign to read only property 'Relatives' of object '[object
> Object]'

I'm very new with NgRx and Immer so i don't know what i'm doing wrong. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to modify the immutable person, which is forbiden. the correct way of updating your person would be

```
mutableOn(PersonActions.addRelatives, (state, { relatives }) => {
     return {
       ...state,
       person: {
         ...state.person,
         relatives,
       }
     };
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I will try that but i was just following the docs of ngrx-etc, which has the following example: 
mutableOn(update, (state, { id, newName }) => {
    const entity = state.entities[id]
    if (entity) {
      entity.name = newName
    }
  }),
and it's says: With the mutableOn function we are able to directly perform state mutations in reducers with less noise, and more concise code.